# Copy Cells values from Excel sheet into an array

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet abc.xlsm" and I have values in "A1" to "A15" in this sheet. I want to copy till 10th row, and then store all the values in an array using VBA.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, please be more specific in your questions: most questions should have at least some bit of code of what you have tried. At any rate this should work, with a couple extra notions:

```
Sub copy()
'Declaring an array - if you know the data type you can type is as well
Dim varray As Variant
'Declaring other variables - don't need to be separeted, just for clarity
Dim i As Long, iLenghtArray As Integer, rgData As Range, rgTarget As Range

'This is to dimension your array - you have tell VBA the lenght of it, or use REDIM
ilengtharray = 10

'Setting the range reference
Set rgData = Sheet1.Range("$A$1:$J$1")

'Then set the array = to the range you set above
varray = rgData

'Then you can interate over your array like so:
For i = 1 To UBound(varray, 2)
    Debug.Print varray(1, i)
Next

'You can also directly past your array into a suitable range
'Setting destination range:
Set rgTarget = Sheet1.Range("$A$2:$J$2")
rgTarget = varray

End Sub
```